# Meteor JS: What is the best way to store states for a specific template instance?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm learning about Session and reactive data sources in Meteor JS. They work great for setting global UI states. However, I can't figure out how to scope them to a specific instance of a template.

**Here's what I'm trying to do**

I have multiple contenteditable elements on a page. Below each is an "Edit" button. When the user clicks on the Edit button, it should focus on the element and also show "Save" and "Cancel" buttons.

If the user clicks "Cancel", then any changes are eliminated, and the template instance should rerender with the original content.

**Here's the code I have so far**

```
// Helper
Template.form.helpers({
  editState: function() {
    return Session.get("editState");
  }
});

// Rendered
Template.form.rendered = function(e){
  var $this = $(this.firstNode);
  var formField = this.find('.form-field');
  if (Session.get("editState")) formField.focus();
};

// Event map
Template.form.events({
  'click .edit-btn' : function (e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Session.set("editState", "is-editing");
  },

  'click .cancel-btn' : function (e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Session.set("editState", null);
  },
});

// Template
<template name="form">
  <div class="{{editState}}">
    <p class="form-field" contenteditable>
      {{descriptionText}}
    </p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="edit-btn">Edit</a>
  <a href="#" class="save-btn">Save</a>
  <a href="#" class="cancel-btn">Cancel</a>
</template>


// CSS
.edit-btn
.cancel-btn,
.save-btn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.cancel-btn,
.save-btn {
  display: none;
}

.is-editing .cancel-btn,
.is-editing .save-btn  {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**The problem**

If I have more than one instance of the `Form` template, then `.form-field` gets focused for each one, instead of just the one being edited. How do I make so that only the one being edited gets focused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render a template with `data`, which is basically just an object passed to it when inserted in to a page.

The data could simply be the key to use in the `Session` for `editState`.

eg, render the template with `Template.form({editStateKey:'editState-topForm'})`

you could make a handlebars helper eg,

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('formWithOptions', 
  function(editStateKey){
    return Template.form({editStateKey:editStateKey})
});
```

then insert it in your template with

`{{{formWithOptions 'editState-topForm'}}}` (note the triple `{`, `}`)

Next, change references from `Session.x('editState')` to `Session.x(this.editStateKey)`/ `Session.x(this.data.editStateKey)`

```
Template.form.helpers({
  editState: function() {
    return Session.get(this.editStateKey);
  }
});

// Rendered
Template.form.rendered = function(e){
  var $this = $(this.firstNode);
  var formField = this.find('.form-field');
  if (Session.get(this.data.editStateKey)) formField.focus();
};

// Event map
Template.form.events({
  'click .edit-btn' : function (e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Session.set(this.editStateKey, "is-editing");
  },

  'click .cancel-btn' : function (e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Session.set(this.editStateKey, null);
  },
});
```

Note: if you are using `iron-router` it has additional api's for passing `data` to templates.

Note2: In meteor 1.0 there is supposed to be better support for writing your own widgets. Which should allow better control over this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks, a little confused about where `editState-topform` comes from. I just stumbled upon a solution to a similar problem which takes the approach of putting in the id of the template instance into the Session object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034556/what-is-the-proper-way-to-manipulate-template-instance-in-meteor-framework?rq=1

Comment: This answer was assuming that you are re-using the `form` template and needed to instantiate it with different options each time (being the name of the `Session` to use). If you're using different templates with but only want one editable at a time. The better solution is to store the active 'template' in a session variable.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of policy I avoid Session in almost all cases. I feel their global scope leads to bad habits and lack of good discipline regarding separation-of-concerns as your application grows. Also because of their global scope, Session can lead to trouble when rendering multiple instances of a template. For those reasons I feel other approaches are more scalable.

Alternative approaches

## 1 addClass/removeClass

Instead of setting a state then reacting to it elsewhere, can you perform the needed action directly. Here classes display and hide blocks as needed:

```
'click .js-edit-action': function(event, t) {
    var $this = $(event.currentTarget),
    container = $this.parents('.phenom-comment');

    // open and focus
    container.addClass('editing');
    container.find('textarea').focus();
},

'click .js-confirm-delete-action': function(event, t) {
      CardComments.remove(this._id);
},
```

## 2 ReactiveVar scoped to template instance

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {  
  Template.hello.created = function () {
  // counter starts at 0
  this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
};

Template.hello.helpers({
  counter: function () {
  return Template.instance().counter.get();
  }
});

Template.hello.events({
  'click button': function (event, template) {
    // increment the counter when button is clicked
    template.counter.set(template.counter.get() + 1);
  }
});
}
```

http://meteorcapture.com/a-look-at-local-template-state/

## 3 Iron-Router's state variables

Get

```
Router.route('/posts/:_id', {name: 'post'});

PostController = RouteController.extend({
  action: function () {
    // set the reactive state variable "postId" with a value
    // of the id from our url
    this.state.set('postId', this.params._id);
    this.render();
  }
});
```

Set

```
Template.Post.helpers({
  postId: function () {
    var controller = Iron.controller();

    // reactively return the value of postId
    return controller.state.get('postId');
  }
});
```

https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#setting-reactive-state-variables

## 4 Collection data

Another approach is to simply state by updating data in your collection. Sometimes this makes perfect sense.

## 5 update the data context

Session is often the worse choice in my opinion. Also I don't personally use #3 as I feel like being less tied to iron-router is better incase we ever want to switch to another router package such as "Flow".