# Meteor: Use in file variables to keep track of state, or use Session?

Tags: meteor

Currently in my Meteor app, I have a boolean variable at the top of my layout file that keeps track of wether the user has closed the menu in desktop view.

```
var closedMenuInDesktopView = false
```

Also in another point in my app I use a boolean variable at top to keep track of wether the app is currently saving or not.

```
var saving = false
```

Everything in my app is working ok but I notice in the example Meteor apps, they use the Session to keep track of state variables within the app. Is it better to do it this way instead of putting javascript variables at the top of the file that can hold value?

Comment: You should only use the `Session` object instead of ordinary variables if you need reactivity. That's the short answer, but on the other hand, you can always manage without reactivity. Reactivity will make your code shorter, but using traditional variables will make your code execute faster (you manually have to update dependencies though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For template code, I think you have three choices:

---

### Session

#### advantages

- Reactive
- State is restored after a hot code push (HCP)

#### disadvantages

- Pollutes the global namespace
- Doesn't work if you have more than one instance of your template.

#### use when

- You need reactive state across an HCP
- You need to preserve state after a template is destroyed. For example if you want to remember your last search on your posts page when you come back to it.

---

### [Scoped Reactivity](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity)

#### advantages

- Reactive
- Promotes code isolation and reuse

#### disadvantages

- State is **not** restored after an HCP
- Slightly more verbose than `Session`

#### use when

- You want to use a `Session` variable, but don't care if you lose state after the template is destroyed. In my case, that's most of the time.

---

### Regular variable (file scope)

#### advantages

- Simple

#### disadvantages

- Not reactive. This usually implies a lot more jQuery code.
- Doesn't work if you have more than one instance of your template.

#### use when

- You need a constant.
- You need a non-reactive state for a singleton template. For example, tracking if a function has ever run before.

Comment: good overview. see my answer here for code examples including some taken from David Weldon's blog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939903/meteor-js-what-is-the-best-way-to-store-states-for-a-specific-template-instance/29635163#29635163

Answer (score 1):

Variables that you declare with `var` are only accessible from within that file. This is much more manageable as your application grows.

Session variables have the advantage of being reactive. They often appear in examples because they have clean syntax, and trigger DOM updates. It's best to limit using session variables for the same reasons you [avoid globals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/485020/511387).

If you don't need reactivity, stick with your locals. If you need a few reactive variables, use `Session`. Otherwise, have a look at [`Deps.Dependency`](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency) to learn how to make your own reactive variables.