# How to pass data and append template in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I  have template:

```
 <div class="container">
       {{>sideBar}}
       {{>gamesContent}}
 </div>


<template name="gamesContent">
         <div class="listGames">
            <div class="row" id="list_game">
                {{#each games}}
                    {{>gameInfo}}
                {{/each}}
              <!--/games--> 

              </div>
         </div>
</template>

  // On server 
 Meteor.methods({
getListGame: function (params) {
    this.unblock();
    var games = HTTP.call("GET",urlAPI,{params:params});
    return games.data;
}
 });

// On client
Template.gamesContent.games = function () {
return Session.get('games');
}

Meteor.call("getListGame", {order: "hot", store:"ios", limit:'24' }, function ( error, result ) {
        if(result.status) {
            Session.set('games', result.data.games);
            Session.set('cursor', result.data.cursor);
        }

});

Template.games.events = {
 'click #show_mores': function (){

 var cursor = Session.get('cursor');
  Meteor.call("getListGame", {order: "hot", store:"ios", limit:24, cursor:cursor },     function ( error, result ) {
            if(result.status) {
                var gameMores = result.data.games;
                console.log(gameMores);
             // i want to append more games here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to click #show_more , it will get data and append #list_game. How to get template and pass data this, then append list_game? Please help me?
Otherwise, Can use scoll Jquery in Meteor?

Comment: Yes you can use every jquery plugin you want. Your Meteor.call looks like a mongo query. Why dont you use Collections to get your data? Your example is a bit obscure. Do you want games to be a resultset from a collection which you want to iterate over?

Comment: Thank you, I dont use database minimongo of Meteor. Datas are got from API ( store by MYSQL). On server Meteor I has called API but on client I dont How to pass data to template then append view

Comment: I have updated Code on server you can see again.Thanks for reply and help me!

Comment: duplicate. answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29667864/861010

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to manipulate template instance in Meteor framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034556/what-is-the-proper-way-to-manipulate-template-instance-in-meteor-framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a very small example for you. I hope i catched up your problem.

```
//Container for gamesContent, just for a better look behavior
<template name="gamesContentContainer">
  <div class="container">
    //I removed your sidebar
    {{> gamesContent}}
  </div>
</template>


//Your gamesContent template
<template name="gamesContent">
  <div class="listGames">
    <div class="row" id="list_game">
      {{#each games}}
        {{> gameInfo}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>
    <button id="loadmore"></button>
  </div>
</template>

//GameInfo template for every game    
<template name="gameInfo">
  <div>
    {{type}}
  </div>
</template>
```

When your gameContent template was rendered you should get the data from server and pass it to your template. To make it easier i took some example data. The data you receive from server (Meteor.call) should look like this.

```
Template.gamesContent.rendered = function() {

  var data = [{'type' : 'JumpnRun', 'year' : 1990}, {'type' : 'Shooter', 'year' : 2005}, {'type' : 'Simulation', 'year' : 1992}];

  //Now we have to save the data into a session variable.
  //Every times this sessionvariabale is changed, all dependencies will change.
  Session.set('games', data); 
}

//Now we have to put this data into our template.
Template.gamesContent.helpers({
  games: function() {
    return Session.get('games');
  }
});
```

I was not sure if this worked for you till now.
If you'd like to load more data, you just have to set the Session variable with new content.

Set an eventHandler on the button:

```
Template.gamesContent.events({
  'click #loadmore': function() {
  var data = [{'type' : 'JumpnRun', 'year' : 1990}, {'type' : 'Shooter', 'year' : 2005}, {'type' : 'Simulation', 'year' : 1992}, {'type' : 'JumpnRun', 'year' : 1990}, {'type' : 'Shooter', 'year' : 2005}, {'type' : 'Simulation', 'year' : 1992}];

  Session.set('games', data);     
  }
});
```

This is just a small example. Despite i would take care to save all the data in session variables. Maybe a clientside collections is better. Read more about in the docs.

Comment: It's useful and clear, I can see . Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. If you like the answer you can upvote and accept it but maybe this is still not working for you through missing reputations. Nice weekend.